# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python

I am trying to use the first function into the other 2 functions. I'm getting an error. Here is the code I'm using.I'm quite new to Python, any help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
inputFile = "File.xlsx"

def add():
     cols = ["A", "B","C"]
     df = pd.read_excel(inputFile, usecols=cols)
     df.insert(4, "D", "0")
     df.dropna(subset = ["B"], inplace=True)
     df = df.replace(np.nan, '--', regex=True)
     df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_',' ')
     return add

def out1(df): 
     df.to_excel("output1.xlsx", index=False)
     writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output1.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
     workbook  = writer.book
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
     ws = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
     ws.autofilter(0, 0, df.shape[0], df.shape[1])
     writer.save()

def out2(df):
      df.to_excel("output2.xlsx", index=False)
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output2.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
      workbook  = writer.book
      df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
      ws = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
      ws.autofilter(0, 0, df.shape[0], df.shape[1])
      writer.save()

out1(add) 
out2(add)
```

Comment: You're not calling the `add` function, it should be `out1(add())`

Comment: And `add()` should end with `return df`, not `return add`

Comment: Plase post the traceback to more easilty spot the failing line and control flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add()` function should `return df` instead of `return add` - you're returning the function name, not the variable you're creating, and you also need to call the `add()` function at the end - `out1(add())` instead of `out1(add)`